# Change app window form on Mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, javafx

Is there any way to change app window form from the rounded corners to strict rectangular form like Windows 8 or like pallete component in Aqua LaF in JavaFX or at least Swing (through some system props)?

Comment: Why would you want that? The window appearance is expected by the user and it would feel wrong if it changed.

Comment: Good point, but i don't think that "user experience" will be crushed by some little design changes, also i'm sure that someone would like little changes =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about JavaFX (as your tags state) you can use `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` and add whatever borders you want:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(new Text(50,50,"Hello"));
    root.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue;");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about css =)